# Reset the Windows boot loader

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I have a laptop with 2 HD, the first C: is an SSD and there is installed Windows, the second D: where there was data. I create from Windows a partition in D: about 300 GB in order to install Ubuntu. I succeeded to install Ubuntu and when I started the pc I had grub that asked me which SO start.

Now, in order to delete Ubuntu and have only Windows I delete the partition where Ubuntu was through the management disk application of Windows.

Now when I turn on the pc I have only the command line of GRUB and I do not know what to do, the only thing that work is F12 and starting the windows boot loader how can I restore the situation in which I have only windows and when I turn on my laptop windows start?

I post an image of my situation from the manage application of Windows. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ourEW.png

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing Startup Repair as described in the article
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

The problem will be getting into it without the Windows bootloader.

For that, see the various options in the article
[How to Boot to Advanced Startup Options in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-boot-advanced-startup-options-windows-10-a.html).
Try first
[Option One](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-boot-advanced-startup-options-windows-10-a.html#option1)
for booting from
*Settings > Update & security > Recovery > Advanced startup > Restart now*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply I follow the instruction but after all Windows said me : "Start up repair couldn't repair your pc" and give me a path to a log file. Do you want to post this log file?

Comment: Try the other options until you find one that works. In the worse case, you will need to do an [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) from boot media.